# Dropzone.js - how to fire sendmultiple event when a submit button click while other events are running as usual

Tags: file, events, dropzone.js, uploading

In Dropzone.js, I want processing, uploading, and other events to run normally but I want to send files and formData when the submit button is clicked.

If I set autoProcessQueue to false, other events are all not fired until processQueue() is called.

How can I display uploading processing and files when files are selected but not sending immediately but when the submit button is clicked?

```
autoProcessQueue: false,

var myDropzone = this;

$('.submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});

this.on("processing", function(file) ...
this.on("completemultiple", function() ...
```

The two above functions have to be fired when files are selected.